# Excel VBA - Do Depending on Trigger

Tags: excel, vba, triggers

I am trying to change the mail body depending on the macro which trigger the macro called "SendFromGmail"

```
Sub SendFromGmail()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set NewMail = New CDO.Message
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("H22")
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H14")
    Set rng3 = Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("H18")

    'bla bla bla
    '...
    '...
    If rng1.Value > 0.02 Then
        HTMLBody = "XYZ is up more than" & RangetoHTML(rng1)

    ElseIf rng2.Value > 0.02 Then
        .HTMLBody = "XYZ is up more than" & RangetoHTML(rng2)

    ElseIf rng3.Value > 0.02 Then
        .HTMLBody = "XYZ is up more than" & RangetoHTML(rng3)

    End If
```

But if `rgn1` is above 0.02 and then `rgn2` is changed and rise above 0.02 the mail is only sent for `rgn1`.

I want to change the subject according to macro the request came from

```
'This is on Sheet3
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Range("H22").Value > 0.02 Then
        Call SendFromGmail
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'This is on sheet4
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Range("H14").Value > 0.02 Then
        Call Gmail
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What it's doing is *`"if a=b then do x or else if a=c then do y"`* and I *think* what you want it to do is "**`"if a=b then do x."`** *`and`* **`"if a=c then do y."`**... right?

Answer (score 0):

You make worksheet calculate events pass the relevant range:

```
'This is on sheet3
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("H22").Value > 0.02 Then SendFromGmail Range("H22") ‘ pass the relevant range reference to SendFromGmail()
End Sub

'This is on sheet4
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("H14").Value > 0.02 Then Gmail Range("H14")
End Sub
```

And change SendFromGmail() sub to accept a Range parameter

```
Sub SendFromGmail(rng As Range) ‘the sub wants a Range parameter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set NewMail = New CDO.Message

    'bla bla bla
    '...
    '...
    If rng.Value > 0.02 Then
        .HTMLBody = "XYZ is up more than" & RangetoHTML(rng)
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

You can also change the body in relation to rng sheet:

```
Select Case rng.Parent.Name
    Case "Sheet3"
        .HTMLBody = ... ‘your text to account for coming from Sheet3
    Case "Sheet2"
        .HTMLBody = ... ‘your text to account for coming from Sheet2
End Select
```